# Which is the best way to insert data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

While writing data to mongodb, we are checking if the data is present get the _id and using save update it else using insert add the data. Read save is the best way if you are providing _id in the query while saving it will update/insert based on if the _id is present in the db. Is the save the best method or is there any other way.

Comment: Save is more performant at saving the entire document and update is far more performant at saving specific fields, also only update can do certain functions like `$inc`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation

[`db.collection.save()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save)

> Updates an existing document or inserts a new document, depending on its document parameter.

[`db.collection.insert()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db-collection-insert)

> Inserts a document or documents into a collection.

If you use `db.collection.insert()` in your case you will get duplication key error since it will try to insert new document which has same `_id` with an existing document. But instead of using `save` you should use the [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update) method.

Comment: So if i have _id then save is the best method ?

Comment: @aravchr YES `save` is

Answer (score 2):

If you have all data available to save, just run [`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) each time but use the `upsert` functionality. Only one query required:

```
db.collection.update(
   ['_id' => $id],
   $data,
   ['upsert' => true]
);
```

If your `_id` is generated by mongo you always know there is a record in the database and `update` is the one to use, but then again you could also `save()`.

If you generated your id's (and thus don't know if it comes from the collection), this will always work without having to run an extra query.

Comment: Always use update with upsert if you aren't sure. otherwise insert for creating new is good. :)